# Mac as dns server on local lan

Tags: macos, dns, xampp, dnsmasq

I'm a web developer in an office, and I often have to let some other collegues to see the websites I'm working on.
On my mac, I've installed XAMPP and for every site I set up a virtual host, so for example mywebsite.local is available for me.
For my collegues what I do at the moment is, on their hosts file, point mywebsite.local to my Mac IP. Of course it's very annoying.

I was wondering if I could use, locally in my office, my mac as a DNS server for all my collegues, without editing everytime their hosts file.

So, if they looks for mywebsite.local, first they look if it's somehow mapped on my mac, and then they looks on a DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

If they install [Bonjour for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=en_US), `mywebsite.local` should automatically resolve to your computer.